Loading Components in SvelteKit for Generic Routes
I'm working on a SvelteKit app where I need to conditionally load one of two components, Comp1 or Comp2, based on server-side logic. Here's a simplified overview of my setup:
+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import Comp1 from "$lib/components/Comp1.svelte";
    import Comp2 from "$lib/components/Comp2.svelte";
    export let data;
</script>

{#if data.number == 1}
    <Comp1 text="1" />
{:else}
    <Comp2 text="2" />
{/if}

+page.server.ts
export function load({ params }) {
    return { number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1 }; // Return 1 or 2
}

I want to optimize loading by avoiding the inclusion of both components if only one is needed.
Is there a strategy in SvelteKit that allows for component preloading based on server data, or any best practices to ensure only the necessary component is loaded?
Using dynamic import causes flickering while the component is being loaded.
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    export let data;

    let Component: any;
    
    onMount(async () => {
        if (data.number === 1) {
            const module = await import("$lib/components/Comp1.svelte");
            Component = module.default;
        } else {
            const module = await import("$lib/components/Comp2.svelte");
          Component = module.default;
        }
});
</script>
    
<svelte:component this={Component} text={data.number.toString()} />

UPDATE:
I have now managed to load the components dynamically in the +page.ts file seamlessly and without any flicker:
+page.ts
export async function load({ params }) {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // 1 or 2

    // Dynamically import the component based on the `number`
    const component = number === 1 ? (await import("./Comp1.svelte")).default : (await import("./Comp2.svelte")).default;
   
    return {
        number: number,
        component: component,
    };
}

+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
</script>
    
<svelte:component this={data.component} text={data.number.toString()} />

What am I trying to do?
Now, I am trying to extend this dynamic component loading approach to handle generic routes such as /[slug]/ where some pages/components might require backend logic. For example, a contact page might need server-side code. How can I integrate backend functionalities in such a setup where the [slug] route is generic?
I understand that it might be simpler to create specific routes like /contact, but in real-world scenarios, my app includes a language path like /[language]/, resulting in routes such as /en/contact and /de/kontaktieren. Managing multiple files for each language variation becomes impractical, so I'm looking for a scalable solution within the generic [slug] structure.
src/
└── routes/
    └── [language]/
    └── [slug]/
        ├── +page.ts
        └── +page.svelte

